# printing buffer from ReceiveFrom terminates thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networking

I have a thread in C# that broadcasts from a UDP socket every 1 second

on a different thread, I have this

```
 while (true)
 {
  if (m_UdpReceiveSocket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
  {
   EndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, s_BroadcastPort);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

   m_UdpReceiveSocket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref ep);

   Console.WriteLine("testing");
   Console.WriteLine( ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer) + "  " + ((IPEndPoint) ep).Address + ":" + ((IPEndPoint) ep).Port);
  }

  Thread.Sleep(1);
 }
```

If I comment out the second call to Console.WriteLine, everything works fine, the other thread broadcasts and this thread receives the information, but if I use the second Console.WriteLine (even without priting the EndPoint) then the thread quits without any exception the second time Console.WriteLine is called

thank you

problem solved, I just needed to take into consideration how much I receive before converting to string

as a side question why can't I see my packets in Wireshark ?

Answer (score 0):

As for the sidenote. I believe my colleague had the same issue the other week. You will not see packets in Wireshark if your client is the same machine as the server.

Comment: but I am broadcasting, everyone can be my client

Comment: what is your wireshark filter?